# MySQL Two Table Query Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables A & B.

```
Table A

GROUP #  |  GROUP NAME
   1         group a
   2         group b 
   3         group c
```

Table B will have a column with group # and then a bunch of other data.

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a query that will return the `GROUP NAME` from TABLE A and the number of rows associated with each group name from TABLE B.

Essentially I'm trying to get the following output:

```
GROUP NAME | COUNT
  group a      x
  group b      y
  group c      z
```

I've been trying variations of the following to no avail...

```
SELECT DISTINCT "GROUP NAME", COUNT(*) from A, B where A.GROUPNUM = B.GROUPNUM;
```

Comment: See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) Your column `GROUP NAME` should _not_ be single quoted. Rather it should be quoted with backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to apply the aggregate `COUNT()` over the group `GROUP NAME` (using `GROUP BY`) to get the count you are looking for.  `DISTINCT` doesn't come into play in this instance,

Note that a column name with spaces will need to be quoted using backticks, not single or double quotes.  I'm also replacing your implicit join with an explicit `INNER JOIN`, which is the modern preferred syntax.

```
SELECT
  `GROUP NAME`,
  COUNT(B.GROUPNUM)
FROM
  A
  INNER JOIN B ON A.GROUPNUM = B.GROUPNUM
GROUP BY `GROUP NAME`
```

Here's a little demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2123f/2

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. However, is there any performance difference (or just preference) to using your code over the following code:

`SELECT 'GROUP NAME', COUNT(B.GROUPNUM) FROM A, B WHERE A.GROUPNUM = B.GROUPNUM GROUP BY 'GROUP NAME'`

Comment: @Kevin It isn't an advantage so much as just a more modern syntax.  The old syntax is still supported by all RDBMS, but was replaced in the early 1990s by the explicit `INNER/OUTER JOIN` Some RDBMS don't support left/right joins via the implicit style.  Performance wise, [they should be the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins/44932#44932)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, note that you will want to use a left join (like below) if you also want to show group names on table a that have no rows on table b.

```
select a.group_name, count(b.groupnum)
  from a
  left join b
    on a.groupnum = b.groupnum
 group by a.group_name
```